# Phone, carrier and country combination

Tags: update

I am interested in getting the Lumia 1520 in eBay or Amazon, the problem is that the 1520 is not officially offered by any carrier in my country. I know I can get any unlocked phone and just put in the Sim card and it will take calls but, will it get the software updates? Anyone can help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

All Windows Phones will get any updates that are released. Updates are released by the country that the phone was intended for sale in, and carrier lock status; So if you were to import from the US, then you'll get updates in line with when the US end users get their updates, even if you're using your phone day to day in (say) Latvia